# Offset loop within a loop not ret

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to create a loop that copies data from one sheet into another, the data from the input sheet goes down column B with no gaps but the data needs to copy to a range on the output sheet in one loop then drop down several rows and start the interior loop again. Once I have 4 sets of data on one sheet I then need to move the loop across the spreadsheet by about 35 columns and begin the loop again.

My main issue is that I cant get the copy and paste positions where I want them to go and the interior loop just pushes the results down and to the right rather than 1 cell below the initial paste position so the results gradually move further across the sheet. Where am I going wrong? Or if there is a better way to go about what I'm trying to achieve?

```
    Dim wsInput As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet
    Dim reps As Long, j As Long, i As Long
    Dim pastePos As Range, copyPos As Range


        Set pastePos = wsOutput.Range("T13") 'first paste destination
        Set copyPos = wsInput.Range("B2")
        For j = 1 To UUTreps
            j = j + 3
            For i = 1 To 5
                pastePos.Value = copyPos
                Set pastePos = pastePos.Offset(, 1)
                Set copyPos = copyPos.Offset(, 1)
                pastePos.Value = copyPos
                Set pastePos = pastePos.Offset(, 1)
                Set copyPos = copyPos.Offset(, 1)
                pastePos.Value = copyPos
                Set pastePos = pastePos.Offset(1, -2)
                Set copyPos = copyPos.Offset(1, -2)
            Next i
            Set pastePos = pastePos.Offset(6, -2)
            Set copyPos = copyPos.Offset(1, -2)
        Next j
```

Comment: Why don't you share as many of the copy and paste addresses as are necessary to recognize a pattern e.g. `B2:D6` to `T13:V17`, `B13:D17` to `T19:V23`...? What does *about 35 columns* mean?

Comment: I have merged cells on the output sheet, on the input sheet its B2:D2 but the output is not T13:T15 its T13,AJ13 then AK13,AP13 and AQ13,AV13, the input has all the data in 3 columns so I just need to keep that range moving down those columns with no breaks but the output sheet has 5 rows of results then an offset of 5 rows then 5 more rows of data until I have 4 sets on 1 page then I need the paste range to move 37 unmerged columns to the right and back to the same row as the first paste but as I'm using merged ranges I didn't know if I would have to reference all the unmerged cells or not.